# Are there any free online collaboration database schema tools?

Tags: database-design, schema, tools

I am interested in a free and simple MySQL tool which can offer online collaboration functionality in creating database general schema. Do you know any?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518277/online-collaborative-schema-design-leverage-google-docs

Comment: that question has 1 year old, I am interested in more recent solutions if there are and you know some of.

Comment: I don't think that the collaboration in database schema design is a sensible way to develop schema. It has side affects if someone is trying to modify the schema without considering the existing data. This is important even if projects are totally new.
I would rather suggest tool like [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org) as your candidate.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @Mike - can you elaborate on why you are looking for a tool that does this?

Comment: I'm considering adding a Wiki on project GitHub to collaborate and discuss the data-model.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Vertabelo](http://www.vertabelo.com). Vertabelo is an online database designer working under Chrome and Safari developed by company I work for.

Vertabelo focuses on online collaboration in the visual database schema creation area. The most important feature of this tool is that it allow to share database models across the team and collaborate on them via web browser. It also allow to have public model link with possibility of embeding diagrams in your webpage/blog/wiki.

Others Vertabelo features include:

- Support for PosgreSql, MySQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, DB2, SQLite, HSQLDB
- Dynamic/Visual search
- Live database model validation
- Model versioning
- Forward engineering
- Reverse engineering

Vertabelo is free to use for academic projects and have commercial versions for larger database projects.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>You should check http://schemabank.com/ it seems to do all you want</strike>

Other alternative are <strike>[solution blueprint](http://www.solution-blueprint.com/bpf-portal/web/guest/home)</strike> or [creately](http://creately.com/Draw-UML-and-Class-Diagrams-Online) they are general propose colaborative UML design tools, but probably will also be useful for your needs

Comment: Looks like schemabank.com is gone

Answer (score 2):

You could use subversion(SVN) as a way to work cooperatively on the structure of the database.   It is also very useful when trying to figure out who changed what and when.  It also gives you the ability to rollback changes to your code if a modification didn't work or caused problems.

I have often used SVN as a way to manage the code for databases, stored procedures and permissions for both MySQL and SQL Servers.  It also provides a way to lock a file, so that no one else can edit it while you have it open.

Subversion Server:
http://subversion.tigris.org/

You can then install Tortoise which can integrate with Windows to give you point and click access to your code.

Tortoise SVN Client:
http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/

You do need to have an Apache 2.2 server installed,

Here is a tutorial I found on the web which looks fairly straightforward.
http://svn-ref.assembla.com/subversion-server-guide-windows.html

Other solutions exist like sourcesafe and CVS, just depends on what you feel comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

WWW SQL Designer

http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/?keyword=default